# Kong Api Gateway - HMAC Signature does not Match

Tags: hmac, kong

```
I am trying to implement HMAC Authentication with Kong, 
I am getting error “HMAC Signature does not match” .
I am making HTTP request using Postman Rest Client. 
Can some one verify my request parameter below.
Credential of Consumer:
Username: "test"
Secret: "test123#"

Http Request Detail:

Date:Thu, 05 Sep 2019 09:56:28 GMT
host:172.17.0.3
Authorization: hmac username="test",algorithm="hmac-sha1",headers="date",signature="YTg5NmQwMjhmMzVmYWNhZmQyZTQwNmY5ZTVkMmUzNDM4NDAxNmY3MA=="

Http Response:

Http Code:401
Response Body:
{
message:"HMAC Signature does not match"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I did generation for signing string "Date: Thu, 05 Sep 2019 09:56:28 GMT". Yes you need space after date.
2. The signature should be MduuZsP0dKRPKGoMSTft/fT+Qmc= for hmac-sha1 secret is "test123#"
   I made this [document](https://medium.com/@gandautama/kong-konga-hmac-with-postman-1410855191a3) for anyone who might need it (relating to kong hmac).